# Lowest detectable power of a laser?

Tags: optics, laser, quantum-optics

What is the lowest power of a laser beam which is still detectable?

More precise: If the intensity of my laser beam is reduced by a factor of $10^{-8}$, can I still detect it? Of course this depends (a) on the power of the laser and (b) on the sensitivity of my detector.

Say that a further restriction is the fact, that the power of the laser must not be too high, since optical devices like mirrors and beamsplitters are used...

Comment: You **do** mean "reduce by a factor of $10^{-8}$ there, not merely losing a micropercent of your power? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since single photon detectors exist, the answer is yes. Providing you have a few photons per second.

Answer (score 0):

Lasers are emitters of synchronized photons. You can cut the intensity of the beam to only emit one photon at a time, experiments have shown lasers that could emit photons as low as 1 a second i believe. Your sensor would have to be able to detect and record the same for you to detect the weak laser. You would need to have every other possible light source shielded or removed.
Examples of detectors that can detect this low level of activity include things like night vision glasses as they have photon intensifiers, so just put a photon intensifier on your detector if your detector cannot see the low level laser by itself. Other examples include Gamma ray detectors and scintillation crystals. (Your cell phone can act as a gamma ray detector by using the lens as a scintillation tube but you must blackout all other light by using a filter, usually electrical tape.)